# WebApi Odata 406 Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I've recently tried to implement a WebApi service that implements Odata.  For my reference I've been using the below links.  In my own code and when running the example, making requests via Fiddler will only return 406 errors.  Has anyone run into similar problems?

Thanks

[WebApi Odata post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx)

[WebApi Odata Example](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/903afc4e11df#Samples/Net4/CS/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ReadMe.txt)

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Which operations are you getting the 406 error on?

Answer (score 1):

There exist two namespaces and assemblies because the two versions of OData are incompatible, though they can be used side-by-side.

Use System.Web.Http.OData for OData v3 and use System.Web.OData for OData v4. in your odata controller

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/416) tracking this issue. The problem here is that any exception during execution gets converted to a HttpError and the ODataFormatter doesn't understand HttpError right now.